# What is wrong with this code of setting up cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

```
setcookie(DG, 1, time()+86400*30);//once blocked always blocked
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

I set the cookies. Then it doesn't work. Cookie is simply not set. What's wrong?

print_r($_COOKIE) shows nothing. What's wrong?

Comment: I noticed that $_COOKIE shows up on next visit but not on this visit. Is this the normal way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that behavior is normal.

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

See [the docs for setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie)

Answer (score 1):

Cookie is some information that the server asks the client(browser) to store. When you execute `setcookie()` the server sends the cookie key value pair to client through `Set Cookie` header. You can inspect this by chrome dev tool or firebug.

From there on, if the cookie is valid and same page is requested the client sends that cookie to server.

[$_COOKIE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) contains information of only that cookies that the server has received from the client for that request.